# Why stringified objects differs from the original

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is such local function (in functional component with state provided useState hook) that has a deal with the state

```
      let setContainer = container => {
        let newState = {...state, files: deleteAllFromTo(state.files), container}
        let newStateIntermediate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newState))
    
        console.log('-----------------')
        console.log(newState)
        console.log(newStateIntermediate)
        setState(newStateIntermediate)
      }
```

Why the newState and newStateIntermediate are able to be different?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on `console.log` to test deep equality. As ASDFGerte and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23392111/6281832) have pointed, it might be lazy. Use, for instance, [lodash.isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) for that. If it happens to return `false`, then inspect the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your sugestions. The problem was that in the first case 'to' is a property of the audio object, but in the second one 'to' is a property of audio[0].